# Error handling of empty json in android studio

Tags: android, json, api

I am trying to build a simple news  app that fetches news headlines from the internet but I am facing some problems in doing this.
In my app if my if the json is not parsed I just get an empty recycler view. In this case I want to parse the json again can someone please help me in doing this

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MainActivityViewModel mainActivityViewModel;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.news_view);


        mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
        mainActivityViewModel.init();
        mainActivityViewModel.getNews().observe(this, new Observer<List<NewsData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<NewsData> newsData) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        init();

    }

    private void init(){
        Log.d("","=========================intializing Recycler view======================");
        System.out.println("executing init()");
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mainActivityViewModel.mutableLiveData.getValue(), this);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

This is NewsRepository.java

```
public class NewsRepository {

    MutableLiveData<List<NewsData>> liveNews = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private static  NewsRepository instance;
    public static NewsRepository getInstance(){
        if(instance != null)
            return instance;
        instance = new NewsRepository();
        return instance;
    }



    private static final String LOG_TAG = "NewsRepository";
    private static final String newsAPIurl = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=google-news-in&apiKey";

    List<NewsData> newsDatalist = new ArrayList<>();

    public void getLiveNews(){
        new FetchJSONAsyncTask().execute();
    }


    public class FetchJSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Log.d("Backgroumd thread" , "Fetching json");
            URL url = createUrl();
            String jsonRespone = "";
            try {
                jsonRespone = makeHttpRequest(url);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Background" , "Could not Load url");
            }
            extractNewsfromJSON(jsonRespone);
            return null;
        }

    }
    private URL createUrl() {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(NewsRepository.newsAPIurl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error with creating URL", exception);
            return null;
        }
        return url;
    }

    private String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            urlConnection.connect();
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"there was an error in makeHTTPRequest"  , e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    private String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }

        }
        return output.toString();
    }

    private void extractNewsfromJSON(String newsJSON){
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(newsJSON);
            String a = jsonObject.getString("status");
            System.out.println("=================================================");
            System.out.println(a);
            JSONArray newsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");

            if(newsArray.length()  > 0){
                for(int i =0 ;i<  newsArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject article = newsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title = article.getString("title");
                    String desc = article.getString("description");
                    String urltoimg = article.getString("urlToImage");
                    String readmore = article.getString("url");
                    NewsData obj = new  NewsData(title , desc, readmore , urltoimg);
                    newsDatalist.add(obj);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem parsing the JSON results", e);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is MainActivityViewModel

```
public class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private NewsRepository instance;
    MutableLiveData<List<NewsData>> mutableLiveData;

    public void init(){
        if(instance != null)
            return;
        instance = NewsRepository.getInstance();
        instance.getLiveNews();
        mutableLiveData = instance.liveNews;
    }

    public LiveData<List<NewsData>> getNews(){
        return mutableLiveData;
    }

    public void refreshNews(){
        instance.getLiveNews();
    }

}
```

Comment: kindly share your json response please

Comment: Where is PostExecute method in your AsyncTask?

Comment: If the json is not parsed successfully at first, why do you want to parse it again ? Will it fix itself in the second time ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with you code lies in this function:

```
 public MutableLiveData<List<NewsData>> getLiveNews(){
        new FetchJSONAsyncTask().execute();
        MutableLiveData<List<NewsData>> liveNews = new MutableLiveData<>();
        System.out.println("==========================================");
        liveNews.setValue(newsData);
        return liveNews;
    }
```

FetchJSONAsyncTask is an asynchronous task, you are returning liveNews before the data is fetched from the API. It's blank and hence you are getting empty RecyclerView.

Here is what you can do, Create liveNews a class variable instead of creating a new object each time.

```
public class NewsRepository {

    public MutableLiveData<List<NewsData>> liveNews = new MutableLiveData<>();
    //rest of the code
```

Update your ViewModel to directly get the value from this variable:

```
public class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private NewsRepository instance;
    LiveData<List<NewsData>> LiveData;

    public void init(){
        if(instance != null)
            return;
        instance = NewsRepository.getInstance();
        LiveData = instance.liveNews;
        instance.getLiveNews() // call to fetch JSON first time
    }

    public LiveData<List<NewsData>> getNews(){
        return LiveData;
    }

    //call this function from your activity to refresh the data
    public void refreshNews(){
        instance.getLiveNews(); 
    }
}
```

Now you update your getLiveNews method to just call FetchJSONAsyncTask.

```
public void getLiveNews(){
        new FetchJSONAsyncTask().execute();
    }
```

Now in extractNewsfromJSON method set the value of liveNews:

```
 private void extractNewsfromJSON(String newsJSON){
        try{
            //rest of the code
            liveNews.postValue(newsData);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println(newsJSON);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem parsing the JSON results", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but I am still getting the live data before I extract information from json file can you please help.